# SwiftMailer problem

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I use SwiftMailer in my PHP script to send emails upon HTML form submission.
On the test server it all works fine.
On the production server (different host) it gives me this error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_CLASS in
>   /home/alkal5/public_html/html/swift-mailer/lib/classes/Swift.php
>   on line 18

What could it be?
Thank you!

Comment: Are the PHP versions on the two machines different?  What versions are they?

Comment: Bingo. They use different versions of PHP.
One is PHP5, the other one is PHP4.4.9.
What should I do?

Comment: I enabled PHP5 on the other server, and it worked.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the From and To setting and if both are OK then Please check the new server's email settings.